# Map Alt-k to delete line (by default bound to dd) in .vimrc

Tags: vim

I'd like to map deletion of a line in vim to `Alt-k` rather than the default of `dd` (as is done in Emacs or somewhere similar) and **put the mapping in `.vimrc`**

I'm struggling as a novice with vim. The closest thing I could find on Google was to define the mapping in a session with `:map - dd` but that's not what I want because of the key, and the fact that syntax is slightly different for `.vimrc` over interactive commands.

What should I put in my `.vimrc` to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If works for me if I use the following workaround:

```
" Fix for M-letter bindings
let c='a'
while c <= 'z'
  exec "set <A-".c.">=\e".c
  exec "imap \e".c." <A-".c.">"
  let c = nr2char(1+char2nr(c))
endw
set timeout ttimeoutlen=50

map <M-k> dd
```

Thanks to this answer for finding the workaround:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778961/alt-key-shortcuts-not-working-on-gnome-terminal-with-vim

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want this in normal mode. Try this:

```
:nnoremap <m-k> dd
```

You can put that line in your `~/.vimrc` exactly as it appears.

If you also want it to work in insert mode:

```
:inoremap <m-k> <c-o>dd
```

***Edit:*** Unfortunately it appears this only works in gVim, and a solution other than choosing a different key combination for console Vim could not be found.

Comment: Neither of these work when added to my `.vimrc` file. I've tried some variants too such as removing the `:` and capitalizing the `M-`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know, since it works for me. Those lines--exactly as they are displayed here--should work in your vimrc.

Comment: Hmmm, okay. May I ask - when should colons be added? When I put `map` commands in my vimrc I never put colons at the beginning.

Comment: In the vimrc it doesn't matter. Use them or not, according to your preference.

Comment: Okay. Actually one thing I found: when I list my mappings in the vim command response area, it shows `ë             dd`. Is there something incorrect about my vimrc character encoding?

Comment: That is how it will show up, yes. It should be working when you press `alt-k`;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33188/discussion-between-heptite-and-sridhar-sarnobat).

Comment: A solution to this is given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778961/alt-key-shortcuts-not-working-on-gnome-terminal-with-vim

Comment: Seems like my edits got rejected so I have to create a new answer